# preg match and stripos

Tags: php, preg-match, stripos

I have an csv import function. There is in the csv a column like this 
    ''1. Informatik, Bachelor, 2015, 1. Fachsemester''
       or this
 '' 1. Mathematik, LA Bachelor Gymnasien, 2015,''

If in the line exists 'LA' , so `$fachrichtung='Lehramt'`, 
if there is no LA, `$fachrichtung` is the first word after the number.
here: 1. Informatik, Bachelor, 2015, 1. Fachsemester
`$fachrichtung= 'Informatik'`.
But if the first word ist not Informatik or Physik, then 
`$fachrichtung= 'Sonstige'`.

```
preg_match( '/[\d]+\.(?P<fach>[\w\s]+)/ius', $tmp[6], $aMatches );
$fachrichtung = ( false !== stripos($tmp[6], ', LA ') ) ? "Lehramt" : trim( $aMatches['fach'] );
```

how can i include the last condition ('Sonstige') in code above? I tried it with if and else but it doesn't function.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the value of the `fach` group later and assign the value to `$fachrichtung` accordingly:

```
// $tmp = '1. Mathematik, LA Bachelor Gymnasien, 2015,'; // => Sonstige
$tmp = '1. Informatik, Bachelor, 2015, 1. Fachsemester'; // => Informatik
$fachrichtung = '';
if (preg_match( '/\d+\.(?P<fach>[\w\s]+)/ius', $tmp, $aMatches )) { 
   if (true === stripos($tmp, ', LA ') ) {
      $fachrichtung = "Lehramt";
   } else if ("Informatik" !== trim( $aMatches['fach'] ) && "Physik" !== trim( $aMatches['fach'] )) {
      $fachrichtung = "Sonstige";
   } else {
      $fachrichtung = trim( $aMatches['fach'] );
   }
   echo $fachrichtung;
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/btBYkb).

The regex is OK, I just added a couple of `if ... else`.

The `else if ("Informatik" !== trim( $aMatches['fach'] ) && "Physik" !== trim( $aMatches['fach'] ))` checks if the `fach` group value is not equal to trimmed `Informatik` or `Physik`. If it is not equal, set `Sonstige` value. Else, set the `fach` group value.

Comment: @egokyniker: Upvoting means clicking on the up arrow *once* :).